# iPhone:Removing/Deleting SQLite database?

Tags: iphone

I know how to create sqlite database, inserting data into it, deleting row into it etc. through iPhone development, but i am trying to remove the entire database itself programmatically, but not getting any helps. Please someone guide me how to delete/remove the entire sqlite database itself from device thru code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the Database file in your document directory and not in the Bundle then you can use NSFileManager to delete the file.

Make sure that the isn't open by any progress.

Answer (score 17):

If your db is in Documents you can try:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"youdb.db"];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
}
```

Comment: I got `BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation: vnode unlinked while in use:` error

Comment: I got the same error too `BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation: vnode unlinked while in use`, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NSError *err;

NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

err = nil;

NSString *deleteFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/FileName",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:deleteFileName];

[fm removeItemAtPath:[url path] error:&err];

if(err)

{

NSLog(@"File Manager: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);

}

else

{

NSLog(@"File %@ deleted.",fileName);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Xamarin in Visual Studio this will work nicely.

```
string _FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "databaseFileName.db3");    
File.Delete(_FileName);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete the whole database you'll have to locate it in the file system and delete it there.